# Clarification on null hypothesis, w.r.t pchisq() function in R, and the tail argument

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I'm looking at two functions for testing goodness of fit for a logit regression model (glm).

Firstly anova(), used as

```
anova(null model, test_model, test="Chisq")
```

This is pretty straightforward, as it provides the residual deviance of the two models.

The second, pchisq() test is where I'm getting confused, particularly around the 'TAIL' option of the function.

I'm using it like this..

```
pchisq(test_model$deviance, df=test_model$df.residual, lower=FALSE)
```

It is my understanding that when using lower=FALSE (same as lower.tail=FALSE), our null hypothesis becomes **'the model being tested is different from our null model'**.

Therefore a low p-val from our pchisq() test (say 0.002) would provide support to reject the null hypothesis (p=0.01), ultimately stating that our test model is not significantly different than our null model.

Have I correctly interpreted the results of pchisq() when used with lower.tail=FALSE?

Edit - For refrence, including the 'help' portion of the arguments section of pchisq() function.

```
lower.tail
logical; if TRUE (default), probabilities are P[X ≤ x], otherwise, P[X > x].
```

Comment: Your understanding of the null hypothesis is incorrect. "Is different" is not sufficiently definite to lead to useful information about the distribution of a test statistic and so cannot be used as a null.  Find out (much) more about this by searching our site for posts about p-values and null hypotheses.

Comment: To clarify again, if you would please..  "is different", being reworded to, "is not the equivalent to", as in Model 1 <> Model 2, or Model 1 - Model 2 <> 0, is not a valid application here as a null hypothesis?

Comment: No, it is not, for the reason I gave.  When you say two quantities are the same, you make a definite assertion of the form $x-y=0$. When you say they are different, you have said virtually nothing about either $x$, $y$, or their difference. The distinction is fundamental to understanding hypothesis tests and p-values: that is why you will find so much more information by searching that material.